# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS loses data?

Tags: rest, http, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I used certbot to create a SSL certificate for my domain. It modified my Nginx configuration automatically. Below is the section which redirects http (80) to https (443):

```
server {
if ($host = domain.tld) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
if ($host = www.domain.tld) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.suzaku.pw suzaku.pw;
    return 404;
}
```

That seems to work. But the problem is that any POST/PUT/DELETE request is now interpreted as GET request:

http://domain.tld/api only understands GET

https://domain.tld/api works with all GET/POST/PUT/DELETE

_

Below is the rest of the configuration (where HTTP gets forwarded to)

```
server {
root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name www.domain.tld domain.tld;
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server; # managed by Certbot
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
location ^~ /jenkins/ { ... }
location ^~ /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Is there any obvious error in my config?

Comment: The `return 301` (in your Certbot block) changes POST to GET by design. You can use 307 or 308 instead, but do you really want to be making insecure POSTs to your application? See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I finally understand. I wanted to be certain that this is not some kind of error. If you re-post your comment as answer I'll mark it as solved. :)